# Prism highlighting errors/stack traces?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have Prism display a code block that looks like an error? I've struggled to find an answer as googling 'Prism' and 'error', or anything similar, results in questions about Prism not working rather than displaying code that doesn't work. I guess it would be a custom plugin?

Something like this for example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, yes. Prism has `jsstacktrace` and `javastacktrace` [language highlighters](https://prismjs.com/#supported-languages).